# Is there any experiment to check discreteness of space?

Tags: spacetime, experimental-physics, discrete

This [article](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/article/are-space-and-time-discrete-or-continuous/) from 2015 seems to suggest that there will be experiments to check discreteness of space:

> If space-time is discrete, there should be imperfections. And even if
> rare, these imperfections will affect the passage of light through
> space. No one has looked for this yet, and I’m planning to start such
> a search in the coming months.

I can't find any reference of the experiment being done, so I'm wondering if it was carried out and what did the experiment show.

Answer (score 0):

In the article itself it mentions that there have been previous (failed) efforts to detect discreteness of spacetime:

> If true, this would distort images from far-away stellar objects, either by smearing out the image or by tearing apart the arrival times of particles that were emitted simultaneously and would otherwise arrive on Earth simultaneously. Astrophysicists have looked for both of these signals, but they haven’t found the slightest evidence for graininess.

The author's proposed experiment was apparently to look for "imperfections" in a hypothetical lattice. However, since the author's name doesn't appear to be supplied in the article (?) it's difficult to find what experiments they have actually performed. It is safe to surmise that if the experiment has been performed then it did not detect discreteness: *any* evidence of discrete spacetime would be a major discovery and would have made a big splash.